# C# RichTextBox странное поведение курсора над текстом

Tags: c#, winforms

Имею простое приложение c# Windows form. Далее есть единственная форма с контролом richtextbox, который закреплен на всей форме(по размеру). В боксе есть три строки. При запуске приложения выделяю весь текст мышью, и провожу курсором над текстом. Появляются лаги непонятного происхождения (и курсор вечно обновляется). Код выложу по надобности, ибо его там нет, как такового. Это нормально? И как исправить лаги? Форма имеет задний буфер. Код:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest\n" +
                "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest\n" +
                "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest";
        }
    }
}
```

И это всё. Вот видео, там видно, как моргает курсор: https://youtu.be/AUeUUw8Pt2M
Повторюсь, видно плохо, но видно. Я не знаю, как ещё показать.
P.S.: кода просто больше нет. Это всё.

Comment: [раз](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06d8e1c3-09dc-4ffb-b52f-ea166c4935bf/mouse-cursor-flickering-bug?forum=visualstudiogeneral), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233806/mouse-cursor-flickers-over-selected-text-how-to-prevent-this)

Comment: клик по `Insert` всё решает :-)

Comment: @DigitalCore увы, проблема не исправилась.

Comment: @tym32167 вторая ссылка помогла, немного доработал. Но понимания, почему так происходит не пришло - нет об этом информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, код, который поможет исправить эту проблему:

```
        private bool isRichTextBox;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest\n";
            isRichTextBox = false;
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetCursor(IntPtr cursor);
        private int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR && this.isRichTextBox)
            {
                SetCursor(Cursors.IBeam.Handle);
                m.Result = new IntPtr(1); // возврат истины
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow.Handle);
            this.isRichTextBox = false;
        }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.isRichTextBox = true;
        }
```

Мы отлавливаем событие изменения курсора в оконной процедуре и "не даём" менять курсор(вызываем WinAPI функцию для смены курсора на IBeam), а также возвращаем истину. Также, я добавил событие при выходе курсора за границы контрола(чтобы курсор менялся на Arrow). Также, член isRichTextBox следит за тем, чтобы курсор не обновлялся за границами контрола.
Теперь всё работает.
P.S.: но самое интересное, почему это вообще происходит - мною не было найдено. На 5 ПК, что я тестировал, но одном всплыла эта проблема. И не ясно почему.
Поэтому, если кто-то знает - дополните ответ, буду только рад.